# Referencing a website in-text using Harvard style

Tags: citations

I have the following website page that I need to reference using Harvard style: http://www.ucsusa.org/food_and_agriculture/science_and_impacts/science/what-is-genetic-engineering.html

Is this a correct way to reference this page?

What Is Genetic Engineering? [online] Available at http://www.ucsusa.org/food_and_agriculture/science

And, how can I reference it `in-text`?

Thanks.